# Trouble Opening Flutter App Links in Android 12: Links Redirect to Browser Instead of App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter app's deep links specifically on Android 12 and 13. While testing on devices running lower Android versions, clicking on links prompts a dialog to open the link either in the respective app or the browser. However, on Android 12 and 13, the links consistently open in the browser.

I've taken the necessary steps by creating the `assetlinks.json` file and placing it at the correct path:

> https://<my_domain>/.well-known/assetlinks.json

In an effort to resolve the problem, I manually selected "Supported web links," which consistently opens the links within the app.

I've added sha256 keys for each Play Store, debug, and release in the `assetlinks.json`. Here's a snippet of how my assetlinks.json file looks:

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "my_package_name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["9C:0B:..:D0:9F"]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "my_package_name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["4f:4d:99:..:fd:04"]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "my_package_name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["89:d8:..:f4:21"]
    }
  }
]
```

I've also verified these configurations using the [Digital Asset Links Tools Generator](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator).

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into why the deep links redirect to the browser on Android 12 and 13, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter. Thank you!